# Bash Parsing of output from command with filter

Tags: bash, awk

I have a command that outputs hard drive status.

I am planning to run this in a script for monitoring purposes.
I would like to pull out certain rows and display them such as Slot Number, PD type Raw Size, Drive's position.

How would I do this. (I'm assuming that it would be some sort of awk statement.)
Output is as such (note that the "(\n)" denotes new lines not a formatting choice)

```
Enclosure Device ID: 252
Slot Number: 3
Drive's postion: DiskGroup: 1, Span: 0, Arm: 1
Enclosure position: 0
Device Id: 7
WWN: 5000C50034BB0CD8
Sequence Number: 2
Other Error Count: 0
Predictive Failure Count: 0
Last Predictive Failure Event Seq Number: 0
PD Type: SAS
Raw Size: 2.728 TB [0x15d50a3b0 Sectors]
Non Coerced Size: 2.728 TB [0x15d40a3b0 Sectors]
Coerced Size: 2.727 TB [0x15d3ef000 Sectors] 
Firmware state: Online, Spun Up
Device Firmware Level: 0003
Connected Port Number: 2(path0)
Inquiry Data: SEAGATE ST33000650SS    0003Z290VK2V
(\n)
(\n)
(\n)
Enclosure Device ID: 252
Slot Number: 4
Drive's postion: DiskGroup: 1, Span: 0, Arm: 1
Enclosure position: 0
Device Id: 8
WWN: 5000C50034BB0CD8
Sequence Number: 2
Other Error Count: 0
Predictive Failure Count: 0
Last Predictive Failure Event Seq Number: 0
PD Type: SAS
Raw Size: 2.728 TB [0x15d50a3b0 Sectors]
```

(continues like this)

### **EDIT:**

I would like to display them as

```
Slot Number: 3
Drive's postion: DiskGroup: 1, Span: 0, Arm: 1
Enclosure position: 0
Device Id: 7
PD Type: SAS
Raw Size: 2.728 TB [0x15d50a3b0 Sectors]ors] 
Firmware state: Online, Spun Up
Device Firmware Level: 0003
(\n)
Slot Number: 4
Drive's postion: DiskGroup: 1, Span: 0, Arm: 1
Enclosure position: 0
Device Id: 8
PD Type: SAS
Raw Size: 2.728 TB [0x15d50a3b0 Sectors]ors] 
Firmware state: Online, Spun Up
Device Firmware Level: 0003
```

Comment: how do you want to display them?

Comment: it's not clear. Please specify exact output..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to extract the lines of interest, you can use `egrep`:

```
cmd | egrep '^((Slot Number)|(PD Type)|(Raw Size)):' \
    | sed 's/^Slot Number/\n&/'
```

Comment: this doesnt keep a newline between sections though.

Comment: @dwarfCode : Enhance the above egrep reg expression to include blank lines with `...|^$'` . Good luck to all.

Comment: But that gives me 3 blank lines I want just 1 between sections